# Build self service Microsoft Partner Center portal using Graph API ( web app )

Tags: reactjs, express, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to build a self service portal for microsoft partner center where customer can login and see their subscription/license details and can even add managed services or a licence that they require to their tenant.

I'm just a newbie with APIs so a detailed setpwise response would be appreciated
using Reactjs and Express currently

Thanks

I have tried and succeeded in getting the users to login ( but since the partner center web app is linked to my tenant only users in my tenant can access and not the customer )

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.